# Erro ao inserir em lote usando OracleCommand

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Preciso otimizar uma aplicação de carga que percorre um banco e grava em outro banco de dados, mas isso **tem que ser feito** através de uma aplicação **Windows Forms**.

Estou fazendo usando o `ArrayBindCount` do *OracleCommand*, mas está retornando **erro de referência nula** ao passar o parâmetro, porém já verifiquei e o vetor de entrar ao criar o parâmetro está normal e não tem nenhum objeto nulo na linha que dispara o problema:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(txtDestino.Text);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.ArrayBindCount = totalRegistros;
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into solicitacao (cd_codigo) values (:cdCodigo)";
List<int> array_CodSolicitacaoNovo = new List<int>();
array_CodSolicitacaoNovo.Add(12);
array_CodSolicitacaoNovo.Add(13);
array_CodSolicitacaoNovo.Add(14);
//ERRO NESTA LINHA ABAIXO
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("v_soli_cd_codigo", array_CodSolicitacaoNovo.ToArray());

//Executado apenas uma vez
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Se não possui objeto nulo o erro estaria dentro do método `new OracleParameter`? **Estou usando a dll Oracle.DataAccess 4.112.3.0**.

**Obs: não posso utilizar Stored Procedures para fazer os inserts.**

Answer (score 1):

Consegui descobrir uma solução, o problema era especificar o tipo do dado e se era de entrada ou saída na hora de criar o parâmetro:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("v_soli_cd_codigo", OracleDbType.Int32, array_CodSolicitacaoNovo.ToArray(), System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));
```

Ao executar o insert não deu mais erro e gravou todos os dados do vetor. Não sei porque quando a entrada é um vetor preciso usar o overload do método, mas funcionou. \o/

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo, porque você não utiliza o foreach para preencher com tipos primitivos, ou ainda passando um array de string para uma stored procedure?

Dê uma olhada como ficaria o foreach:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(txtDestino.Text);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.ArrayBindCount = totalRegistros;
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into solicitacao (cd_codigo) values (:cdCodigo)";
List<int> array_CodSolicitacaoNovo = new List<int>();
array_CodSolicitacaoNovo.Add(12);
array_CodSolicitacaoNovo.Add(13);
array_CodSolicitacaoNovo.Add(14);


foreach (var item in array_CodSolicitacaoNovo)
{
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("v_soli_cd_codigo", item.ToString());
}

//Executado apenas uma vez
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abs

Comment: Oi Andre, na verdade desta forma que você sugeriu ele não esta fazendo um insert em lote, este é o modelo que eu tinha antes e precisei alterar para otimizar. Tenho uma base de dados de mais de 200.000 itens e fazer uma chamada de banco para cada insert acaba sendo ruim. Por isso tem que ser passado o array de valores direto na criação do Parameter, mas ta dando erro lá dentro. :)

Comment: Andre, quanto ao uso de procedure, esqueci de comentar mas não posso utilizar por restrições do ambiente de banco e requisitos técnicos.

Comment: Eu tenho uma rotina que faz isso, mas ao invés de executar assim, eu gero um script usando o StringBuilder e vou adicionando várias linhas de INSERT, por exemplo e executo de uma vez só, com a possibilidade de transacionar a execução.

Comment: Mas a execução de todas esta linha também é feita via código? Ou você gera esse arquivo como um txt e pega ele e roda através do pl/sql por exemplo?

Comment: Mais ou menos assim:

//Criacao do Script
StringBuilder scriptSQL = new StringBuilder();
scriptSQL.Add(string.Format("insert into solicitacao (cd_codigo) values ({0})", suainformacao);
scriptSQL.Add(string.Format("insert into solicitacao (cd_codigo) values ({0})", suainformacao);
scriptSQL.Add(string.Format("insert into solicitacao (cd_codigo) values ({0})", suainformacao);

Execução do script
ExecuteNonQuery(scriptSQL.ToString())

Comment: Isto funciona via o OracleCommand? Vários comando aninhados? Sei que funciona direto pelo pl/sql. Funcionando seria um boa alternativa, mas gostaria de aproveitar o código que já possuo sem precisar fazer muitas concatenações que aumentam o risco de erro e dificultam a manutenção. Mas agradeço todo seu apoio. :)

Comment: No caso do Oracle, basta colocar o ponto-e-vírgula no final de cada linha.